# How to get rid of double quotes wrapping serverless-offline html response body?

Tags: node.js, serverless

I'm trying to get a HTML response from my serverless-offline project, but it returns html body wrapped with double quotes, which ruins the page. How can I get rid of the quotes?
[image]

Content-type looks valid

[image]

I have this versions of serverless plugins installed

```
"serverless-base-path-plugin": "0.0.1",
    "serverless-cors-plugin": "^0.2.1",
    "serverless": "1.71.3",
    "serverless-offline": "6.1.7",
    "serverless-optimizer-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "serverless-resources-validation-plugin": "^0.2.0",
    "serverless-helpers-js": "0.2.0",
    "serverless-webpack": "5.3.2",
```

serverless.yml

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  region: eu-west-1
  profile: default
  memorySize: 256 # optional, in MB, default is 1024
  stage: local

plugins:
  - serverless-offline


custom:
  serverless-offline:
    host: 0.0.0.0
    httpPort: 1465
    useDocker: false
    noPrependStageInUrl: true

functions:
  xdomainProxy:
    handler: dist/xdomain-proxy/handler.handler
    events:
      - http:
         path: /api/xdomain-proxy
         method: get
         integration: lambda
         response:
            headers:
                Content-Type: "'text/html'"
```

handler.js

```
'use strict';

var ServerlessHelpers = require('serverless-helpers-js').loadEnv(); // all content must be assembled into a single variable


function render() {
  return ['<!DOCTYPE HTML>', '<link rel="shortcut icon" href="about:blank">', '<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jpillora/xdomain/0.7.4/dist/xdomain.min.js"></script>'].join(' ');
} // Lambda Handler


module.exports.handler = function (event, context) {
  try {
      var html = render();
      context.succeed(html);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    context.fail(err);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, looks like it's serverless-offline version 6 issue. I could find out that it runs json.stringify if you try to return a string. Downgrading to version 5 solved the issue for me.